# Is there any way to adjust windowSoftInputMode programmatically in android

Tags: android

I want to adjust my keyboard when I click any edittext. I use windowSoftInputMode in AndroidManifest but when I use search edittext it covers the whole area.[Keyboard and bottom layout cover whole area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXO8Q.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

Comment: getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);    This Line is not working in activity.  When I try to use getActivity is getting red. I think it's working in fragment. but I want to use it in activity.

Comment: use getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);